# Official Django Tutorial, Test Client, Contexts

Tags: python, django

I am attempting to do the 'legendary' django tutorial, and have run into a couple of problems. Firstly, I am [Stage 5 - Testing](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/intro/tutorial05/), and exploring the Django Test Client, through the interactive shell. The specific problem I am having is in relation to requesting :

```
>>> response.context['latest_question_list']
```

the response I am getting is

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
 TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Everything works fine up until this stage, but having ignored the problem and attempted to continue, I think it may be responsible for errors futher along the course.

I am very new to both Python and Django, and from my digging thus far, have identified that the context, in this case ['latest_question_list'], behaves as a dictionary, to which questions are appended to, so my question is why is nothing being placed within this dictionary?

This is code from my views.py which I believe is responsible for that functionality:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect, HttpResponse
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.views import generic

from .models import Choice, Question


class IndexView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'polls/index.html'
    context_object_name = 'latest_question_list'

    def get_queryset(self):
        """Return the last five published questions."""
        return Question.objects.order_by('-pub_date')[:5]
```

I apologise if this question as poorly written, as it is my first time. Furthermore, for any of those who are more inquisitive or require further information about my code, please follow the link to this git, which contains an up to date example - [Github.](https://github.com/theoford1/04_django_intro)

Many thanks to anyone who is patient enough to help me solve this prolem.

------------->> Ammendment

Building on from the answer from jpic, hopefully this explains how I got the response object:

```
>>> from django.test import Client
>>> # create an instance of the client for our use
>>> client = Client()
>>> # get a response from '/'
>>> response = client.get('/')
>>> from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
>>> response = client.get(reverse('polls:index'))
>>> from polls.models import Question
>>> from django.utils import timezone
>>> response = client.get('/polls/')
>>> response.content
>>> response.context['latest_question_list']
```

I hope that this can answer your question. Many thanks for getting back quickly! Again apologies for formatting.

Comment: response.context is None, how do you get the response object ?

Comment: hey jpic? does this answer your question?

Comment: What does `response.content` display? Have you remembered to set up the test environment, as [in the tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/intro/tutorial05/#the-django-test-client)?

Answer (score 3):

Welcome !

The problem with your question is that you don't show us how to get the same response object as you do on our own, therefore, we can't reproduce your problem.

The problem with your context object is that it's None, request.context is None in your case so that's why '[...]' - which calls `__getitem__` - fails hence the exception "NoneType has no attribute `__getitem__`".

For me django test client's response has a context all right:

```
$ ./manage.py test polls
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
.WARNING: Attempting to work in a virtualenv. If you encounter problems, please install IPython inside the virtualenv.
WARNING: Attempting to work in a virtualenv. If you encounter problems, please install IPython inside the virtualenv.
--Return--
None
> /tmp/04_django_intro/mysite/polls/tests.py(43)test_index()
     41     def test_index(self):
     42         response = self.client.get('/')
---> 43         import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()

ipdb> response.context
[{'False': False, 'None': None, 'True': True}, {'exception': 'Resolver404', 'request_path': u'/'}]
ipdb> c
...
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 4 tests in 5.121s

OK
Destroying test database for alias 'default'...
```

To get this debugger inside my test, this is the code i added to polls/test.py:

```
def test_index(self):
    response = self.client.get('/')
    import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()
```

Don't forget to `pip install ipdb`, or use `pdb` here instead of `ipdb`.

Also, please consider reading [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) and [PEP0257](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/), if you haven't already, but perhaps you've read it after starting polls/tests.py.

Answer (score 3):

The problem described by the OP will also occur if you use Jinja2 templates instead of DTL.
So if you have followed along in the tutorial but have amended `settings.py` to use jinja2, you will have the following lines in a python shell:

```
import django
django.setup()
from django.test.utils import setup_test_environment
setup_test_environment()
from django.test import Client
# create an instance of the client for our use
client = Client()
# get a response from '/'
response = client.get('/')
==> Not Found: /
response.status_code
==> 404
from django.urls import reverse
response = client.get(reverse('polls:index'))
response.status_code
==> 200
response.context['latest_question_list']
==> Traceback (most recent call last):
      Python Shell, prompt 12, line 1
    builtins.TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

As you can see, `response.context` is None because Jinja2 has not filled it. Instead use `context_data` when using Jinja2:

```
response.context_data['latest_question_list']
==> <QuerySet [<Question: What's up?>]>
```